# Sencha Touch: Windows Phone does not scroll to end of page

Tags: javascript, extjs, scroll, windows-phone, touch

I have a Sencha Touch 2.4 website with multiple views.
All views scroll as expected on iOS and Android. But on Windows Phone they do not scroll.
When I scroll down I can see the other content, but when I stop scrolling the page scrolls back to the top.
I can also see at the scrollbar it doesn't expect the rest of the page.
Underneath the code of a view.

```
Ext.define('App.view.Welcome', {
  extend : 'Ext.Container',
  xtype : 'Welcome',
  config : {
    styleHtmlContent : true,
    scrollable : true,
    layout : 'vbox',
    items : [ {
      docked : 'top',
      xtype : 'titlebar',
      title : 'Title',
      items : [ {
        xtype : 'button',
        iconCls : 'help',
        align : 'right'
      } ]
    }, {
      xtype : 'image',
      baseCls : 'logo'
    }, {
      xtype : 'label',
      html : 'Introduction text',
      width : '100%'
    }, {
      xtype : 'element1',
      width : '100%'
    }, {
      xtype : 'element2'
    } ]
  }
});
```

I have tried several things. Also changes on the css. 
But cannot find a solution for the scroll problem yet.

Please, Help!

Comment: It looks like Ext.ux.AccordionList introduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an issue for the AccordionList creator at GitHub.
After testing his AccordionList demo on a Windows Phone it had the same issue.